# Getting an error when try to do Heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby, heroku, sqlite, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I am making small Sinatra app and trying to put it on Heroku server.

when I do Heroku run rake db:migrate, Heroku is giving error "Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required  by ActiveRecord)." .

While I have a sqlite3 gem in development group in my gem file.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'activerecord', :require => 'active_record'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', :require => 'sinatra/activerecord'
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development
gem 'rake'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'thin'
gem 'shotgun', :group => :development
gem 'pry'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem "tux"
gem 'rack-flash3'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'database_cleaner', git: 'https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Also, please see below environment file

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rack-flash'

Bundler.require

configure :development do
  ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
     :adapter => "sqlite3",
     :database => "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.sqlite"
   )
end

configure :production do
  db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/mydb')

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
     :adapter => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
     :host     => db.host,
     :username => db.user,
     :password => db.password,
     :database => db.path[1..-1],
     :encoding => 'utf8'
  )
end

require_all 'app'
```

I also did "bundle install --without production" and pushed everything on Github. Does anyone have any possible solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you need to remove `group => development` from the sqlite3 gem so it will load in your production environment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler (and more reliable in the long run) to install PostgreSQL in your dev environment so that you'll be developing, testing, and deploying with the same stack?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from having `group => development` in the `gem 'sqlite3'` line of your gemfile.

What you need to understand is what environment your Heroku server is using.

To check, try running `heroku run console -a your-app-name` from the command line (you need the Heroku CLI installed).

Now run `Sinatra::Base.development?` or `Sinatra::Base.production?`

The results of running these commands should help you understand why including `group => development` is causing `rake db:migrate` to fail on Heroku and not your local dev environment.